# I am trying to create a switch case default function in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var day;
  switch (new Date() .getday()){
    case 0:
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
    case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;
    case 2:
    day = "Tuesday";
    break;
    case 3:
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;
    case 4:
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
    case 5:
    day = "Friday";
    break;
    case 6:
    day = "Saturday";
    break;
  }
  $('#demo').html(case"");
});
```

And the HTML tags is something like this I used the same code for the javascript as well.

```
<h1> Switch case in jQuery</h1>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: What's it supposed to output and what is not working? Do you want to output `$('#demo').html(day);` maybe?

Comment: You have not asked a question, explained what you want this to do, or what the problem with it is.

Comment: FYI, for stuff like this you should really rather use an array of weekday names, that you can look the corresponding day up in using the day number as index.

Comment: Or use `Intl.DateTimeFormat` or `toLocaleString` to get the day name. But this question just has syntax errors.

Comment: *Always* check the browser console for errors - you should see something like `.getday is not a function`

Comment: You don't need a `default:` in your `switch` (based on the question title) as `.getDay` will only ever be 0-6.  For any other switch, add `default: data = "Unknown"; break;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems. First `getDay` not `getday` and then `$('#demo').html(day);` instead of `$('#demo').html(case"");`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var day;
  switch (new Date().getDay()){
    case 0:
    day = "Sunday";
    break;
    case 1:
    day = "Monday";
    break;
    case 2:
    day = "Tuesday";
    break;
    case 3:
    day = "Wednesday";
    break;
    case 4:
    day = "Thursday";
    break;
    case 5:
    day = "Friday";
    break;
    case 6:
    day = "Saturday";
    break;
  }
  $('#demo').html(day);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p id="demo"> </p>
```

But there is simple way to show week day:

```js
console.log(new Date().toLocaleString('en-us', {  weekday: 'long' }));
```